# Why do I get multiple XHR requests when network is slow?

Tags: php, jquery, networking, xmlhttprequest, keep-alive

When I execute an action (upload a post request) on my website from my home network (Slow, less than 1Mb/s upload), the Chrome dev tool shows several XHR requests :

[image]

While when I execute the same action but this time from my 4G phone network (Quicker, around 10Mb/s upload), the chrome dev tool shows only one (sometimes 2) XHR requests :

[image]

How and why does it decides to split like that? Is it link with the fact that it is transfer-encoding chunked?

[image]

or maybe because of the keepalive timeout of 5?

The problem is that when there are those several XHR requests and that I reload the page before all the requests ends up to code 200 (which can take several minutes sometimes), I lose some data.

Thanks.

EDIT:

As asked in the comment, here is the code I use for this part (I tried to clean it a bit by removing the parts not related to the problem, hope it helps)

For exemple, if I update or add a "tag" to my note (my code is a note taking app "Evernote" type), the changed is trigered here in my index.php file :

```
<div class="name_tags"><span><input onfocus="updateidtags(this);" id="tags'.$row['id'].'" type="text" placeholder="Tags ?" value="'.$row['tags'].'"></input></span></div>
```

then the JavaScript file where all my functions are is called :

```
var editing = 0;
var lastudpdate;
var editingnote=-1;

$( document ).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){ checkedit(); }, 1000);
});

function updateidtags(el)
{
    editingnote = el.id.substr(4);
}

function checkedit(){
    if(editingnote==-1) return ;
    var curdate = new Date();
    var curtime = curdate.getTime();
    if(editing==1 && curtime-lastudpdate > 1000){
        updatenote();
    }
}

function updatenote(){
    var headi = document.getElementById("inp"+editingnote).value;
    var ent = $("#entry"+editingnote).html();    
    var entcontent = $("#entry"+editingnote).text();
    var doss = document.getElementById("dossier"+editingnote).value;
    var sousdoss = document.getElementById("sousdoss"+editingnote).value;   
    var tags = document.getElementById("tags"+editingnote).value;

    $.post( "updatenote.php", {pass: app_pass, id: editingnote, dossier: doss, sousdossier: sousdoss, tags: tags, heading: headi, entry: ent, entrycontent: entcontent, now: (new Date().getTime()/1000)-new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60})
    .done(function(data){
        if(data=='1'){
            editing = 0;
            $('#lastupdated'+editingnote).html('Last Saved Today');
        }
        else{
            editing = 0;
            $('#lastupdated'+editingnote).html(data);
        }
    });
    $('#newnotes').hide().show(0);
}
```

and finaly the update php file is called (I removed from it the part where it send data to the database) :

```
<?php
    [...]
        
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $heading = $_POST['heading'];
    $entry = $_POST['entry'];
    $entrycontent = $_POST['entrycontent'];
    $now = $_POST['now'];
    $seconds = $now;
    $dossier = $_POST['dossier'];
    $sousdossier = $_POST['sousdossier'];
    $tags = $_POST['tags']; 
        
    $filename = "entries/".$dossier."/".$id.".html";
        
    [...]

    $str = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    
    if ($entry != ''){
        if (!fwrite($handle, $entry)){
            die("Error while writing to html file");
        }  
    }   
    fclose($handle);
?>
```

If it can help to see what the entire code looks like, I can provide the Github repo but I wasn't sure if I could do that here.

Comment: Are you sure it's not something you're doing on the javascript side?  Like, setting a timeout on the http requests you're making or something, and then making them again on timeout?

Comment: Please provide the JavaScript code you are using.  Keep-Alive should not be related in this instance, as it does not close pending requests. Keep-Alive implies that the client has received the response from the server and to the retain the persistent connection by waiting for 5 seconds for the client to issue a new request before the connection is considered dead and a new connection is needed to be established to serve another request.

Comment: Hi Daniel and Will, thanks for your comments! I tried to add as much as informations as I could in a new EDIT in my post. Hopefully it helps to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Daniel Farrell was right, the problem comes from the fact I send a new request every second which is too short for the previous request to finish when network is too slow. Here is the problematic code part :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){ checkedit(); }, 1000);
});
```

It executes the checkedit() function every 1 second and launch updatenote.php which write to a file but on slow network, this operation takes more than a second for some big files so the setInterval function call updatenote.php again before the last one finished. Then it creates a new request.